# Fourier transform of function $f(x)$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

I have to find the Fourier transform of the function $$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}(x^2 + a^2)}$$ where $a > 0$.

I start out by checking if the function is differentiable. Since it is defined everywhere, and also its derivative is defined everywhere there are no problems.

Then I check if $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx < \infty.$ To see this we integrate:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}(x^2 + a^2)}dx = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{(x^2 + a^2)}dx = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\frac{1}{a}  \Big|_0^\infty  = \frac{1}{a}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - 0\right) < \infty $$
and so we can compute the Fourier transformation using 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{iyx} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{iyx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}(x^2 + a^2)}dx$$
I hope I didn't make a mistake in the first integral. For the second is there a trick to compute it because it seems so hard to calculate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Use residu theorem on $$[-R,R]\cup\{Re^{i\theta }\mid \theta \in [0,\pi]\}.$$

Comment: I haven't heard about this.

Comment: Have you heard about the inversion formula? If you compute the Fourier transform of $e^{-|x|}$ you will get a constant tomes your function and the inversion formula will give you the answer. Or you can use contour integration as suggested by Surb. But there is no simple, basic Calculus way of finding the FT.

Comment: @mandella Cauchy's residue theorem is famous in one complex variable. It makes many integrals of this type possible to solve which is difficult with most normal real analysis methods. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem

Comment: You don't do complex integrals without knowing the Residue theorem